# How to convert lines to polygons for a large number of features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, concave-hull, feature-to-polygon

I'm using ArcGIS Pro to try to convert line features into a polygon of the outer extent of lines (will eventually be a part of a Python tool). The line dataset has a little under 316,000 features and the Feature to Polygon tool is taking forever/hasn't yet run successfully. Is there a better/quicker way to do this in ArcGIS? Here's a screenshot of an example of the data:
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are after the concave hull for your lines.

Comment: @PolyGeo overall, that's what I'm after. I'm happy with this shape of the lines... just looking for an efficient way to get it into a polygon.

Comment: I'd try memory workspace for lines and output first

Answer (score 1):

'Outer' lines have only 2 **spatially unique** intersection points with other lines. So, this workflow:

```
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(in_features="many_lines #", out_feature_class="in_memory/mpart", join_attributes="ALL", cluster_tolerance="0.001 Meters", output_type="POINT")
arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management(in_features="mpart", out_feature_class="in_memory/sparts")
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(in_dataset="sparts", fields="Shape", xy_tolerance="0.001 Meters", z_tolerance="0")
arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis(in_features="many_lines", near_features="sparts", out_table="in_memory/abc", search_radius="0.001 Meters", location="NO_LOCATION", angle="NO_ANGLE", closest="ALL", closest_count="0", method="PLANAR")
arcpy.Frequency_analysis(in_table="abc", out_table="in_memory/freq_table", frequency_fields="IN_FID", summary_fields="")
arcpy.JoinField_management(in_data="many_lines", in_field="OID", join_table="freq_table", join_field="IN_FID", fields="FREQUENCY")
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features="many_lines", out_feature_class="in_memory/less_lines", where_clause='"FREQUENCY" =2')
```

will significantly reduce original set:

[image]
[image]

Main question I have: how your lines were generated without prior knowledge of polygon???